# Dropdown in IE does not refresh in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dropdown

I have a dropdown which has a 'click' event where I call a rest service and update the options in the dropdown using jquery, So the problem is that the options are not getting updated in IE. It works fine in chrome & others.

sample code

```
       <select class="dropdown">
          <option value="1">Column1</option>
          <option value="2">Column2</option>
        </select>

         $(.dropdown).click(function () {

            var $dropdown = $(this);
            var contrId = $(this).attr('id');

            var selectedVal = $(this).val();
            $($dropdown).empty();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/FakeAPI/GETDATA")',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'POST',
                data: { 'id': '10' },
            }).done(function (data) {
                // Clear drop down list
                $($dropdown).empty();
                // Fill drop down list with new data

                var $option = $("<option />");
                $option.attr("value", '').text('Select Column');

                $($dropdown).append($option);

                $(data).each(function () {
                    // Create option
                    var $option = $("<option />");
                    // Add value and text to option

                    $option.attr("value", this.Text).text(this.Value);
                    if (selectedVal == this.Text) {
                        $option.attr("selected", "selected");
                    }
                    // Add option to drop down list
                    $($dropdown).append($option);

                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Use change, not click

Comment: @epascarello cannot do that , as I want to update the calling dropdown's options, before I can select an option

Comment: `$(.dropdown)` must be `$(".dropdown")`

Comment: typo while putting it here, the actual code on my system has the quotes

Comment: Wait, you are clicking on the select and filling in the options? Seems like a bad idea. Than you want to use focus, not click

Comment: Also no need to cast a jQuery object to a jQuery object: `$($dropdown).empty();` can be written `$dropdown.empty();`

Answer (score 0):

Working in I.E 9,10 and 11 tested

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown").click(function () {
                var $dropdown = $(this);
                var contrId = $(this).attr('id');
                var selectedVal = $(this).val();
                $($dropdown).empty();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/FakeAPI/GETDATA")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'id': '10'},
                }).done(function (data) {
                    // Clear drop down list
                    $($dropdown).empty();
                    // Fill drop down list with new data

                    var $option = $("<option />");
                    $option.attr("value", '').text('Select Column');
                    $($dropdown).append($option);
                    $(data).each(function () {
                        // Create option
                        var $option = $("<option />");
                        // Add value and text to option

                        $option.attr("value", this.Text).text(this.Value);
                        if (selectedVal == this.Text) {
                            $option.attr("selected", "selected");
                        }
                        // Add option to drop down list
                        $($dropdown).append($option);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is IE cache requests by mistake. Add `cache:false` to your ajax request and probably it fix the issue by adding `_={timestamp}` at the end of your requests.

```
$.ajax({
       cache:false,
       url: '@Url.Content("~/FakeAPI/GETDATA")',
       dataType: "json",
       method: 'POST',
       data: { 'id': '10' },
```